# Athena query on sales data with 7-day time frame

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, subquery, presto, amazon-athena

**sample_input_table**

```
user  name  action      date             collection
 1    aaa    view      2020-09-03       {id:"888"}
 1    aaa    view      2020-09-02       {id:"999"}
 2    bbb    view      2020-09-02       {id:"555"}
 3    ccc    view      2020-08-28       {id:"777"}
 4    ddd    view      2020-08-25       {id:"666"}
 1    aaa    purchase  2020-09-09       {operation:"purchase"}
```

I have a table with huge number of rows, the table looks like above.

**question**

1. i want to print the rows which have `purchase` action and
2. at the same time, the user who did `purchase` must have row with `view` action
3. and at the same time, that `view` action will be in the date range of purchase_date(`2020-09-09`) and  purchase_date - 7days(`2020-09-02`).
4. finally, i want a row with `purchase` action and i need one new column `collection_1`.
5. this `collection_1` column consists of `collection` value, which we will grab from `view`rows which is having `min(date)`

**I want to achieve these 5 points in one sql query**

**sample_output**

```
user  name  action      date          collection               collection_1
1    aaa    purchase  2020-09-09      {operation:"purchase"}    {id:"999"}
```

if we see sample output from the sample input

1. our end result have only purchase_events
2. purchased_user had a row with `view` action
3. and that `view` was there in the timeframe of `2020-09-09` and  `2020-09-02`(purchased_date, purchased_date - 7 days)
4. and we have new column `collection_1`, where we grab the value from `view` row which is having `min(date)`

**Can anyone suggest some solution for this?**

Answer (score 0):

I might try:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY date) rn
    FROM sample_input_table t1
    WHERE action = 'view' AND
          EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sample_input_table t2
                  WHERE t2.user = t1.user AND
                  t2.action = 'purchase' AND
                  DATEDIFF(day, t1.date, t2.date) BETWEEN 0 AND 7)
)

SELECT t1.*, t2.collection AS collection_1
FROM sample_input_table t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.user = t2.user
WHERE t1.action = 'purchase' AND t2.rn = 1;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

The strategy above is to first find all `view` records, for each user, which have a corresponding `purchase` record for the same user.  We also compute a row number based on the date, so we know which of these view records corresponds to the earliest date.  By joining this CTE to your original table and then restricting to the first row number, we can find the matches you want.

Note: The demo is in SQL Server, but it should run on Athena with little modification needed.

Comment: Hi Tim, we r missing seven day time frame condition.  I mentioned in the question point no-3. All views will be in the seven day time frame

Comment: @siva I have added a check on the 7 day range as you suggested.

Comment: is there any other approach with Joins or using sub-queries?

Comment: My approach _is_ using joins and subqueries `:-)`

Comment: sorry, my point is with out using `WITH` statements

Comment: Replace `INNER JOIN cte t2` with `INNER JOIN (SELECT ...) t2`.  That is, just inline the contents of the CTE in the query on the bottom.